# Bootstrap 3 col classes and pixel ratio

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap column classes `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6` for one of my divs in my layout but on tablet devices with pixel ratio of 2.2, it seems to be choosing col-xs-12 instead of col-sm-6.

I found a very similar issue [Here](https://coderwall.com/p/ikrswg/bootstrap-3-grid-system-and-hi-density-small-screens-detected-as-xs) however, author's css solution didn't work for me and JS solution made my tablet layout look like a desktop which is not what I'm looking for.

How do I display the content correctly on a tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S5E) ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` of your web page you need to set the viewport to always scale to 1 using the viewport meta tag like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap shows this in their "Getting Started" guide with their basic template: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#template

For further info, here's some good documentation about sizing with the viewport meta tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag